# Node.js express multitenant app

Tags: node.js, express, multi-tenant

We are planning a multi tenant app in node.js and express with mongodb. We would have some core functionality exposed via REST APIs. We would have customized functionality for each customer which would process some data and in turn call the REST APIs. The customized functionality as well as the UI(views and public folder) for each customer would reside in a separate folder for each customer under a parent folder. My questions are:

1. When I add a new customer and create a module for him, I should be able to start using it without having to restart the main module (app.js).
2. I need to redirect the customer to his UI files based on the urls say example.com/cust1/home would go to the parentfolder/cust1/views and example.com/cust2/home would go to parentfolder/cust2/views.

For the prototypes we have node running behind an apache proxy/reverse proxy and run the custom apps on their own ports. But in production we cant have the apps running on so many individual ports or modify the default.conf each time. For the UI we have tried the dynamic routing of express but that didnt work.  We tried doing this in app.js:

```
var cust1 = require('./cust1/custommodule'); //this needs to be done for each new customer module added;
var app = express();

// view engine setup
var basePath = ''; //works if we hard code it to cust1 or cust2 here;
app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
//      basePath = path.dirname(req.originalUrl); //this does not work since the app.set is executed before this is assigned
        app.engine('html', require('ejs').__express);
        app.set('view engine', 'html');
        app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, basePath + '/views'));
        next();
});

app.use('/:custom', express.static(__dirname + basePath + '/public'));
app.use('/cust1', cust1); //request coming with /cust1 should use this module, but this again needs to be done for each new customer module added;
```

Not sure if this is the right way. Any pointers would be appreciated.